# Determine $f$ when $f(t)+f(t^{-1}) = g(t+t^{-1})$

Tags: functions

I have the following equation:

$f(t)+f(t^{-1}) = g(t+t^{-1})$,

where $g$ is a known function. The objective is to determine $f$. Also, assume that $t>0$ and $f,g \geq 0$. My intuition says that $f$ should be

$\frac{1}{2}g(t+t^{-1})$, i.e. $f(t)=f(t^{-1})$.

Comment: What are the domains and codomains of your functions?

Comment: Suppose that $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g \geq 0$.

Comment: Presumably you mean to require $t$ to be nonzero as well?

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah yes, let me correct that. Thank you. I'm mostly concerned with $t>0$ specifically.

Comment: Counterexamples: if $g(x) = x$ then $f(x) = x$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ will work; if $g(x)=x^2$ then $f(x)=x^2+1$ will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that $f$ is not uniquely determined by this functional equation. For example, your proposed solution 
$$f(t)=\frac{g(t+t^{-1})}{2}$$
does satisfy the desired functional equation, but so does the function
$$f(t)=\frac{g(t+t^{-1})}{2}+o(t-t^{-1})$$
...where $o$ is any odd function.

Answer (score 2):

This equation does not give enough information to determine $f$.  For every $t$ such that $t\neq t^{-1}$, $f(t)$ and $f(t^{-1})$ could be any pair of numbers at all whose sum is $g(t+t^{-1})$.  (Note that the restrictions given by different values of $t$ are essentially independent of each other, since the only time they would overlap is in the case of $t$ and $t^{-1}$ but then they give the exact same restriction.)